# How do I create a administration page (with overlay) through the UI

Tags: modal-dialogs

I would like to add an administration page (with overlay) to my site (not programatically). I assume the basic process is:

1. Create a 'basic page'
2. Set the path to /admin
3. Set permissions <-- How do I do this???  I can't see how do I
   restrict the page??
4. Configure overlay - Is it automatic?
5. Add page to admin menu.

I'm stuck on 3, but I could probably use help on 4 and 5.

Thanks!

Comment: Without a module, it is not possible to make a node appear in an overlay.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [Overlay Paths](http://drupal.org/project/overlay_paths) module:

> This is a simple module that enables site builders to use the built-in Overlay for non-admin pages.

However, if the path you've got for the node is under /admin I'm pretty sure that if you configure permissions properly you won't need that module; the overlay should pop up automatically. You'll need to give your users the "Use the administration pages and help" permission, as well as the one to actually use the overlay.

As it's a node, whatever node access solution you have in place will determine the access beyond those two permissions.

Comment: I tried, but the overlay is not used, with nodes, even assigning them a menu item under /admin.

Comment: 1) What do you mean by 'configure permissions properly'.  I'm trying to restrict this custom admin page (node) that even anonymous users can see but I don't see how AND this page is under /admin
2) I get the same behavior as kiamlaluno.  I can manually append #overlay=admin/<page> to any core admin page and it works fine, if I change it to my custom page it no longer works (just jumps back to the non-admin page).  This may be because of the above problem (page is not yet restricted) but this brings be back to the question that I can't find the answer to: how do I restrict a node?

Comment: @user11792 What are you actually asking? How to show a node in the overlay, or how to configure permissions for a node so that your users can view it? It's one question per question around here :) Did you try the overlay paths module as recommended?

Comment: I'm asking the question at the top of the page.  But I assume that it's not a one-step process and entails proper permissions being set, which is why overlay doesn't work.  If there is a way to get overlay to work without setting proper permissions, then I'd be happy to start a new question, but if not then: how do I set permissions for the custom admin page so that overlay works correctly.